# Link in submenu on a Android Device doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css

I have a navigation menu. On desktop and on iPad and iPhone it works fine. Only on an Android device (with chrome) it doesn't work. The submenu opens, but if you want to open a link in the submenu, the submenu closes. So you don't go to the page. I have searched a lot on the internet and tried, but so far not successful... below the simplified code. Hopefully someone can help me.

```
<nav id="nav">

<ul>

  <li>Main 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Main 2
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

     <li>Main 3
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
     </ul>
</nav>

nav ul li ul {
display: none; }
nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is giving me a headache... After hours of searching and trying, I gave up. I think it's impossible to get the hover-effect on all devices well functioning. I have chosen the following solution:

- I use jQuery to show the submenus when you click on the parent. If you click again on the parent the corresponding submenu disappears. There is a maximum of one submenu to be opened.
- For visitors who disabled javascript, I use the 'traditional' css hover-effect.

Below is my code. This is the first time I use jQuery, so if there are more efficient or better solutions, let me know!

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="nietactief nonJSclass">Hoofdmenu 1
      <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 1a</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 1b</a></li></ul></li>
      <li class="nietactief nonJSclass">Hoofdmenu 2
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2a</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2b</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Submenu 2c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nietactief nonJSclass">Hoofdmenu 3
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Hoofdmenu 3a</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Hoofdmenu 3b</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Hoofdmenu 3c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

```
nav ul li.nietactief ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul li.actief > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li.nonJSclass:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $(".nonJSclass").each(function()
  {
    $(this).removeClass("nonJSclass");
  });

$('nav ul li').click(function() {

    var classActief = $(this).attr('class');

if (classActief == 'actief'){

    $(this).removeClass('actief').addClass('nietactief');
} 

if (classActief == 'nietactief'){

    $('nav ul li').removeClass('actief').addClass('nietactief');

}

if (classActief == 'nietactief'){

    $(this).removeClass('nietactief').addClass('actief');

}  


});



});



 </script>
```